# rowSums Error: undefined columns selected

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to use the rowSums function on a data set and I keep getting the same error:
`` Error in `[.data.frame`(southamerica.all, , c(as.character(19711:20001))) : undefined columns selected ``
My code is:
`southamerica.all$Population = rowSums(southamerica.all[,c(as.character(19711:20001))])`.
I have used pretty much the same code (but denoting different columns) and had no issue. There are no N/A values in my data and the columns are of the same length so I am confused as to why this is happening. 
The data I am trying to use this function on is:

```
19711   19751   19801   19851   19901   19951   20001   20051   20101
95.13   107.26  120.69   135.27  149.00  162.02  174.79 186.13 195.71
21.48   24.07   26.90   29.95   33.10   36.42   39.63   42.65   45.22
23.88   25.87   27.90   30.22   32.62   34.83   36.87   38.89   40.90
13.46   15.43   17.55   19.77   22.07   24.30   26.46   27.87   29.03
9.94    10.59   11.42   12.26   13.28   14.38   15.34   16.18   17.06
6.25    7.00    7.99    9.07    10.23   11.46   12.68   13.83   15.01
4.58    5.00    5.58    6.18    6.87    7.62    8.42    9.23    10.05
2.54    2.79    3.18    3.68    4.22    4.78    5.32    5.82    6.25
2.82    2.83    2.92    3.01    3.11    3.22    3.32    3.32    3.36
0.96    1.01    1.09    1.17    1.22    1.25    1.27    1.30    1.33
```

I am unsure as to why I am having this issue as this code:
`southamerica.all$CO2_per_capita = rowSums(southamerica.all[,c(as.character(1971:2010))])`
for different columns in the same dataset worked without issue.

Comment: Your column names show `19711` `19751` etc.  Also, when you do `19711:20001` it is creating a sequence and onlyy some of the columns are present in the dataset.  May be you need to subset `intersect`

Comment: Just use `rowSums(southamerica.all[, 1971:2010])`

Comment: Yes these are the columns I am trying to use the rowSums function on. They show different data to the columns entitled 1971 and 1975 hence the difference names.

Comment: ```intersect``` would work but I need to produce the function: ```southamerica.all$Population``` hence I am using rowSums

Comment: What is the selection criteria of your columns? Do you want to select all columns or column between two numbers or above some number? Anything else ?

Comment: Just the data above, which is part of a bigger dataset. However this is data I created and added to a larger dataset which the other rowSums function was applied to. Does this impact my ability to manipulate the data in the same way?